# How to optimize this code: code takes too long to run when submitted but completes as an individual test case

Tags: python, optimization

This is a LeetCode solution that completes correctly as a test case but times out when submitted against all the test cases. I don't see how to optimize or fix it.

https://leetcode.com/problems/total-hamming-distance/

```
class Solution:
    def num_gen(self, nums):
        for i in range(0, len(nums)):
            for j in range(i+1, len(nums)):
                yield (nums[i], nums[j])

    def hammingDistance(self, n1, n2):
        x = n1 ^ n2
        setBits = 0
        while (x > 0) :
            setBits += x & 1
            x >>= 1
        return setBits

    def hammingDistanceX(self, xBin, yBin) -> int:
        hd = 0
        for i in range(0, len(yBin)):
            if xBin[i] != yBin[i]:
                hd += 1
        return hd 

    def totalHammingDistance(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        thd = 0
        #for p in combinations(nums,2):
        for p in self.num_gen(nums):
            if p[0] != p[1]:

                x = p[0] ^ p[1]
                setBits = 0
                while (x > 0) :
                    setBits += x & 1
                    x >>= 1
                thd += setBits
        return thd
```

Here's the data that causes a time-out:

```
nums =
[9282814,4439757,7056523,8101654,2236683,8940071,9218118,5751130,570240,7158314,427234,1172586,7430633,3375660,2693866,5949386,7250049,5649177,9889905,9744715,7540434,4114710,5357533,9990179,863142,9284000,4372859,5252905,8256873,4311103,2466147,4038490,2817729,7375713,5955510,4985585,3539041,7167771,590877,8112151,9268560,9208291,9505987,9167676,1989570,386506,1252803,8323662,207447,9628703,1360572,220022,6350796,4840156,126908,9339153,9512419,1682477,5586728,4981940,200414,9789449,1473615,1430232,5925973,5611115,3692582,3714224,3250648,2825295,5836232,4985084,3392467,6770023,4197159,5334475,5096085,5610405,5867390,7495923,8887779,7537453,2333222,307129,3913054,3608788,2398157,3486585,3497382,7083871,3936111,5203098,6480494,1526307,6764475,9945834,5895841,8480901,6094917,5310876,7508049,5925992,389071,4011913,2320732,2297502,9396489,2301303,1813830,7323641,5105187,6069118,1967284,3216459,6347415,4609601,7391494,5768511,4542085,4025504,317159,5951529,1406341,3994893,8907304,3098862,6723039,3012828,7759292,8883223,4598583,2042411,7537281,5074439,1332127,1580307,325341,4718714,7234303,6807733,7638284,5057569,8271993,1332608,3862896,7580506,2426013,4576021,3790789,4414115,5266628,6090313,6465382,7492477,6512234,7148243,9604979,1121040,3694525,5849823,9043290,1559427,5150313,1704510,2963227,1382929,3332409,4949508,6888503,3750273,6744680,7128158,312365,9012593,1482972,7564131,6679255,3320030,2255744,7616229,2822474,2238795,3748744,7152754,9803314,6273135,3409087,8483874,2077461,853520,3614846,9619250,1141046,7735144,997121,2365562,3280909,6656652,1751588,3162369,4357120,3933844,3974230,7030798,7818691,880236,2507547,5389667,3927873,6442633,8920946,4547712,1070648,2039605,6989239,161379,1639361,7866894,1560190,1958721,9221453,1193677,7708648,3601737,1431576,9994626,8549982,1168149,9958309,539943,4399478,2085569,6313854,582341,3439486,55111,4343022,4470157,6904321,1905997,5900454,8653304,2982179,6489126,1627554,3838822,2359990,1495662,8981604,8483093,5270926,2481023,6350289,7234452,6015020,8848175,3945939,6046782,4061510,6552755,701043,1331198,425227,2080848,6830917,7596171,4838669,416075,4538718,9039491,181789,4897965,9171703,4603938,1128451,7089535,520360,7605310,7048441,8464101,8409695,9107941,6987117,8695347,2712300,7767823,6034652,3215376,1735058,9710638,3295783,888838,3017781,9368740,5619461,192892,6178464,4857125,3856577,1072674,8990252,1799363,6850951,5773675,8659254,8615850,6652667,3690691,1548875,5377140,563584,7625987,75690,7832764,5892635,1100927,1503358,1578786,8181961,9969964,4652815,2481079,9505683,7905925,8929629,1033514,1989799,9641844,6329137,954433,6815901,8033528,98468,3088319,3207106,2299679,5680929,1863700,6527287,7929812,7464058,4845236,1047845,6270983,1652600,3581079,7380705,6559098,6743244,6582930,5898267,7574862,3842839,9996820,1167941,5637652,1212453,9856813,8376939,6716740,1557712,6586509,599787,334676,4297969,3507453,7917857,7530731,3812943,9793148,9871796,3920686,7727836,8599075,4241286,6807407,5579269,3298795,4794499,3638708,8818506,2183388,4430850,9354773,4814313,8820362,1165226,3731113,7196963,4717553,5418778,6388783,6842574,6507927,5583047,2778507,4584183,9930967,5078260,4987074,1341218,6145457,886831,9546333,7353542,3055581,2368494,6511233,5087458,9227015,7924721,8130957,4167604,7811256,6575435,4829914,8644858,2586967,9344339,4947254,257836,2927002,9435934,8062439,554912,5860350,824245,3543922,8029340,3909174,5848808,30184,190422,7383551,497797,8052103,5676093,9118982,4247004,3337343,8044803,5138770,5015399,1597915,9118464,8777509,4445566,3480273,4693221,9935119,8280991,9525239,7712817,4741143,9649239,6251171,1650894,3779137,5677038,2315687,5642830,2007763,3560991,8249177,9681007,1609546,7714101,4855265,9040648,5721734,3337823,4035051,2025899,921563,5928769,6056021,8944092,5423643,8686971,5707780,980701,7049866,1161765,5485421,1752839,9029861,2438157,5260162,8454807,7486613,5744032,3427931,996560,8094900,2109805,4900617,6078932,3886158,2178762,3431158,2760594,1261992,9220007,6203044,8537785,4737323,911211,5667171,2145506,5840521,2964777,9420247,166162,177864,7587535,9251928,9660288,8666489,5068161,536605,4359491,9538373,7981999,1929255,1774437,3370402,5437881,8321903,7742021,8091372,7823953,7548205,8276816,7111593,8256609,2422875,8506232,4214545,1342108,2964796,3996179,5681419,8361132,5200467,5116744,488905,9078215,2619213,998462,4947947,4072843,7409798,2669682,7244477,4979151,3279245,8522495,7804739,5747707,5284300,5835973,3624628,3428257,3620175,1228398,7890874,7310427,9811177,9678887,1429439,6966001,6394001,4283547,1623322,2407199,6765967,226389,122186,847746,9561537,8609835,4475808,1146521,5555047,9145752,4597904,2526282,6848745,4636101,7584214,9983347,1274696,6676604,5253962,5887030,1432980,5104166,2680083,6466261,8892209,2557063,8611168,7183938,2263200,3449623,2107491,2679796,390341,9645869,4632556,1774311,9008299,9481023,3673039,6337777,3402090,2444253,7882943,9739023,4774655,854757,5929348,1082429,1690226,3105794,5046074,3472372,4847225,887344,3191547,416254,4217748,9510441,3382541,8082632,2794130,1481477,5427975,3967050,4202761,9180642,9054112,8941960,6203519,6047154,5504246,6845857,1074262,702991,560523,120229,7910001,1984228,71379,3163585,3878987,9534455,2132173,5465525,383543,2232017,5021430,1527333,6299324,7368741,9906306,5319657,722337,9602768,4771585,5960311,2379036,9615316,9176532,6159984,3622500,6443117,3544823,7338402,4106511,1204741,3751940,3951127,7149500,7922357,2518718,8865577,2176485,352151,428251,6369481,5472863,1208687,7432898,9308226,3920752,1262807,1711847,3848229,7775281,5974723,9410988,5193662,7661908,4701403,1220905,7283645,2541570,4449405,904259,4229194,8814141,1845857,4809096,2344108,505556,9482193,3460340,5343778,108651,6738622,7037619,3939283,2532036,9618002,9127354,1061185,2260807,7215139,3452095,5777953,3368621,2142724,3023916,7014973,3892561,5718672,3568589,2405585,9121315,9596179,8793284,4371480,6532427,9478105,8126945,4323942,4921797,889525,7375459,9732531,8916369,1897160,6291993,1698448,3414258,5088472,3978446,4392378,3002091,5181223,676747,5571861,5326026,9550564,5225180,7352467,7337100,102487,9766653,7244510,8907403,4107511,209716,677430,4897265,8963513,4901612,7611365,7685626,3847983,9793182,3953945,4420982,3840163,6624444,417753,9320797,2729394,5754392,6556341,3779966,481288,6893341,6709893,9777139,9251823,3743577,9702187,9092070,4227887,9656413,1587611,4029333,8442074,8325017,2369886,5831266,3475523,9927392,534612,2512742,7634611,762659,6987975,4075396,6347381,6926097,7713941,472345,1000517,5287910,7027397,4136328,8963191,100804,565027,8367777,1174296,6644559,3221113,1667528,6337084,5739506,5375229,7102452,9691243,9751975,7008186,9303050,6330653,6784690,5591561,1324038,6011796,1242340,3433912,390027,5146826,3955769,8359927,1314210,618845,2503591,9298466,662787,4073540,6496544,5003123,3672027,2795606,1446674,8205335,5593336,9035153,37846,9530256,3116290,7344568,3540051,8738554,8204638,6948079,2630127,6765125,7496763,9618059,5231687,9875482,8513000,3064209,9196201,3623447,2663745,881385,46077,905428,4870935,6175002,4821913,7422561,4549690,9384563,8777820,4254277,156388,4900157,1170712,8713117,1553978,6944839,4618290,4419627,9983924,3781356,3843018,7982050,2482013,4378620,5282096,4899322,4067645,4733369,978089,8814470,7375360,9885549,8273669,6938341,1681938,4146244,3667402,6710585,8338361,764251,6216874,1984684,4496592,2768055,5666909,5009716,5214735,7423642,4476791,4247735,9958772,1832295,7697363,7861232,3406399,5734615,3125746,8348672,7084004,6736042,1080293,5395431,7246264,3117436,1414858,1429178,7433040,4687377,9898100,3247191,4158896,2585100,6148759,31346,5872579,8555023,1693814,416753,7276819,7343032,7724499,8452784,8723030,9460526,2936893,6756725,8011763,8629625,7785780,9271550,1401243,4509428,7633708,2944226,1254767,521788,6031862,7973448,5357131,5538611,7273879,8922562,7249201,6282974,6514760,5571612,5950551,1458384,4831769,6966376,6163139,5991093,173599,7371746,4732874]
```

Comment: I have not reviewed the code yet, but I do see a nested for loops and inside those a while loop and my experience with these kinds of tests suggests that is not the strategy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Counter class to count the number of 1 bits at each position in the numbers.  Each bit position contributes to the total of hamming distances based on the number of ones and zeros (zeros being the difference between the count of 1s and the size of nums).  The conributing value of each bit position is the product of counts of 1s by counts of 0s"

By applying a mask for each bit positions in the numbers you will obtain distinct values for 1s at each position (1, 2, 4, 8, ...) and a total count of zeros (which is not relevant to the total).

```
from collections import Counter
def hamTotal(nums):
    counts = Counter((1<<i)&n for n in nums for i in range(n.bit_length()+1))
    return sum(c*(len(nums)-c) for m,c in counts.items() if m)

nums = [4,14,2]
print(hamTotal(nums)) # 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [bitwise technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) for counting numbers.

**I quote from Wikipedia**:

> In computer programming, a bitwise operation operates on a bit string,
> a bit array or a binary numeral (considered as a bit string) at the
> level of its individual bits.
>
> On simple low-cost processors,typically, bitwise operations are
> substantially faster than division, several times faster than
> multiplication, and sometimes significantly faster than addition.

I also tried to sketch my own version of your program using the above technique where for each bit position `i` (0 to 31), you count the number of elements in `nums` that have bit `i` set to 1 (**count_ones**) and the number of elements that have bit `i` set to 0 (**count_zeros**). The product of **count_ones** and **count_zeros** represents the sum of the Hamming distances for bit `i`. This operation is repeated for all 32 bits.

```
class Solution:
    def totalHammingDistance(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        thd = 0
        n = len(nums)
        for i in range(32):
            count_ones = 0
            for num in nums:
                count_ones += (num >> i) & 1
            count_zeros = n - count_ones
            thd += count_ones * count_zeros
        return thd
```

Answer (score 0):

For speed you should be using
[bit_count()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_count).

Also, is it a sure thing that we need to compute O(n**2) quadratic distances?
Or is there some [pattern](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/384/did-gauss-find-the-formula-for-123-ldotsn-2n-1n-in-elementary-school) to the sum
that becomes apparent as we add a 3rd number, then a 4th, ... Nth?